# How to fix Life360 API new Cloudflare Error "This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks"?

Tags: python-3.x, cloudflare

Starting on December 20, 2023 Life360 API started throwing this error.

"This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data"

Are others having this issue when trying to hit the API?  I'm using a modified version of the Python Package that was started from [harperreed](https://github.com/harperreed/life360-python)

```
authorization_token = "Y2F0aGFwYWNyQVBoZUtVc3RlOGV2ZXZldnVjSGFmZVRydVl1ZnJhYzpkOEM5ZVlVdkE2dUZ1YnJ1SmVnZXRyZVZ1dFJlQ1JVWQ=="
username = "username@example.com"
password = "mypassword!%$#"
    
api = life360(authorization_token=authorization_token, username=username, password=password)

print(api.authenticate())
```